# AWS Lambda : how to get 'apiKeyId'

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I am currently working on the AWS platforma and Lambda. Please note that this is totally new to me. I am asked to change a code without being knowledgeable on the subject.

I have a lambda code with a lambda_handler() function.

I need to access the value 'apiKeyId'. For now, I have this line of code, that was writen by my predecessor (he left saying "you just have to uncomment this line") :

```
def lambda_handler(event, context):
    id = event['requestContext']['identity']['apiKeyId']
```

However, when I run a test from the lambda window on AWS, I get this error :

```
{
    "errorMessage": "'requestContext'",
    "errorType": "KeyError",
    "stackTrace": [
    "  File \"/var/task/lambda_function.py\", line 61, in lambda_handler\n    id = event['requestContext']['identity']['apiKeyId']\n"
    ]
}
```

If I print the value 'requestContext', indeed, there is no 'identify' value, only this :

```
event =  {'httpMethod': 'GET', 'queryStringParameters': {'q': 'toto'}}
```

Can someone explain to me why there is no 'identify' and 'apiKeyId' value in 'requestContext' ?
Is there another way to access 'apiKeyId' ?

Answer (score 0):

Your `test` even is different that the actual `event` passed to the function through API Gateway. To make the test work, you have to **replicate the event structure** that API gatway is using. That structure is explained in AWS docs:

- [Input format of a Lambda function for proxy integration](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/set-up-lambda-proxy-integrations.html#api-gateway-simple-proxy-for-lambda-input-format)

Comment: Thank you for the doc link. I also tried to run a test from Nightingale, to simulate an external request, but then I cannot see my prints and check the values.

Comment: I changed the code a little and checked it with Nightingale, it works ! But is there a way, when using this Nightingale, to check the content of the request sent to AWS ?

Comment: @theonewhodidnotknow I don't know what Nightingale is. Your question does not even mention it. This is a new issue, thus new question, specific to Nightingale should be made. My answer correctly addresses the problem you originally reported.